# Why href is not working with swipe in bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

`href` is not working in `bxSlider`.

When I write `touchable: false` in `bxSlider` it works fine, but swipe doesn't work. I need both events in to work in `bxSlider`.

```
$('#homeslider').bxSlider();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the below code. It's working fine with both events.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#homeslider').bxSlider();

```
window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide=null;
$(function() {
    // for desktop get link event
    $('#homeslider li a').mouseover(function(event) {
        window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide=$(this);
    });

    $('#homeslider li a').mouseleave(function(event) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide = null;
        }, 200);
    });


    // for mobile touch event
    $('#homeslider li a').on('touchstart', function(event) {
        window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide=$(this);
    });

});

$('#homeslider').parent().on('click', function (event) {
    //Check if we've got a slide under the mouse
    if ((window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide!=null)){
      var hrefUrl = window.bxslider_mouse_over_slide.attr('href');
      window.location.href = hrefUrl;
    }
});
```

});